# Roslyn and Debugging

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, roslyn

The Roslyn CTP has been out for some time now and I've enjoyed playing around with it a little, but there's one obvious question that I haven't seen answered yet. What, if any, benefits will Roslyn bring to debugging?

Anyone who has spent any time doing serious debugging in Visual Studio knows how frustrating it is not to be able to use lambda expressions, and thus LINQ, during debugging. Given that Roslyn is a compiler-as-a-service, will it be possible to make debugging (watch window/immediate window) support these features?

Thanks for anyone with any insight.

EDIT:

To be more specific, the following article details why lambdas cannot currently be used in the immediate/watch window.

[LINQ in Debugger Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/08/26/why-no-linq-in-debugger-windows.aspx)

Is it known whether Roslyn specifically addresses the problems this article details?

Answer (score 6):

> Given that Roslyn is a compiler-as-a-service, will it be possible to make debugging (watch window/immediate window) support these features?

This would have to be implemented by the Visual Studio team - and (theoretically) could be done using their current codebase.

I do suspect that Roslyn, given it's clean architecture, will dramatically simplify their work in implementing these other features, which in turn *may* cause them to be more likely to appear in a future version of Visual Studio (after Roslyn is actually used within VS).

Comment: But do you know if it simplifies the issues with the watch/immediate window or do will these issues remain unchanged?

Comment: @MgSam Right now, the CTP doesn't change this at all.  Just switching to Roslyn wouldn't likely have any effect, though it would make it simpler for the VS team to handle those issues.  Roslyn, itself, doesn't change anything there.